# Segfault popen when command not found

Tags: c++, linux

Wrote a program that has a method that opens a `popen` command to a temporary file, reads the output and parses for use somewhere else in the program. If the command succeeds, program works as expected. However, if the `popen` tries a command that fails, the file still has a valid pointer but when the program tries to read the data  with `fgets` the program seg faults.

Function body:

```
      std::map<std::string,size_t> cols;
      const char* command = command_string.c_str();

      if (FILE *fp = popen(command,"r")) {
          char buff[linesize];
          std::vector<std::string> list;
          std::cout << "here, popen succeeded\n";
          std::cout << fp << '\n';
          while (fgets(buff,linesize,fp)) {
              std::cout << "here, fgets succeeded\n";
              std::string data(buff);
              list.push_back(data);
          }
          parse_cols(list);
          pclose(fp);
      }
      else {
          std::cout << "Failed to open bash shell when trying to run command\n";
          std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
```

With the output:

```
here, popen succeeded
0x1cc2430
sh: my_command: command not found
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Is it possible to handle this error? It's a somewhat useful error, but I'd like to be able to handle it rather then just relying on the seg fault. I tried looking at the `FILE` struct, but seems to be different for different C library versions.

Comment: Is the program segfaulting in `fgets()` itself?  Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: What is `linesize` ?

Comment: I'm [unable to reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb91e96134178f84) a segfault.  Are you sure it's `fgets` crashing, and not your `parse_cols` function behaving badly when given an empty list?

Comment: I am not familar with popen, but the manpage talks about errors (thus NULL) returned when fork or pipe fails or it can't allocate memory. I assume it succeeds, fgets() retuns null (so your while loop is skipped) and your segfault actually happens in parse_cols(list)... As I don't know the code, I can't tell why. You could handle an initial NULL returned from fgets as failure perhaps, but you need to restructure your loop in order to do so properly.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the snippet you've posted, so please create a [mcve] that somebody could compile and run and test.

Comment: The error may be in `parse_cols`, could you add the code of this function to you question?

Comment: Yes it was the `parse_cols` function, should have been fairly obvious to me thanks everyone for pointing this out. Added an empty check on the list vector fixes it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popen is a beast. It only returns `nullptr` when  `fork` or `pipe` fails, but in your case they do not.

However, your program should not segfault. When shell returns failure, you should be reading from a valid (albeit empty) stream. Than `fgets()` returns NULL because end of file occurs while no characters have been read.

Than you are calling `parse_calls` - a function we do not see - but I have reasons to believe it can't handle the empty list. Crash stacks could be of further help when it comes to pinpointing the actual problem, which is not in `popen` or `fgets`.

Comment: Yes that was it, I should have thought to check that since the `while` loop was not executing

Comment: @MartinBoros on a side note, using `popen` in general is probably not a great idea (unless this is a learning exercise).

Comment: Is there a better way to use a `shell` command output in a C++ program? I have to use a fairly old version of `c++0x` by the way. It's for a data monitor system on a QA server that will run once a week, if it fails it's not a big deal but I'd like it to be as reliable as possible

Comment: @MartinBoros it is usually better to access data through some other means, rather than executing the shell - which is too unpredictable and depends on the factors outside of your control (OS version, shell version, etc). However, if your whole task is to execute a program and check it's output, than obviously popen is not a bad choice.

Comment: okay, yes it's just checking the output of a program and logging low quality data that is coming out of it. Thank you for your advice